# COMODO SSL Analyzer Error -14

Tags: security, https

I have a hard time understanding [Comodo's SSL Analyser](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/) error in some cases.

If queried on [smtp.tiscali.it:465](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=smtp.tiscali.it:465),it returns the image below:

[image]

However, if querying in OpenSSL:

[image]
Or [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/help/):

[image]

It seems that it does use SSL protocol there (SMTPS). Why does Comodo return this and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author/maintainer of [COMODO SSL Analyzer](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/).  I've just fixed this bug, so [querying smtp.tiscali.it:465](https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=smtp.tiscali.it:465) now works as you'd expect.

Details, if you're interested:
Querying `smtps://smtp.tiscali.it:465` would've worked without this bugfix.

The issue was this: when the query doesn't specify a protocol, my code refers to `/etc/services`; for "smtp.tiscali.it:465" this gives the answer "urd" (rather than "smtps"), which I hadn't previously whitelisted as an SSL/TLS protocol.

Comment: It is awesome to hear from the maintainer himself. Great work, thanks! :)

Comment: Also, just another query if you are able to look, shouldn't this show as revoked? https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/?url=revoked.badssl.com I am a heavy user of your tool and very happy overall with it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that Comodo's tool does not return a helpful error message upon test failure. Try a different tool instead.

I've always used Qualys' SSL Labs tool for testing as it is very thorough and clear. [Testing your link](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=smtp.tiscali.it%3A465), it returns the error message "Ports other than 443 not supported". You are using Comodo's HTTP(S) web server tool to test the SMTP protocol, which is not supported.

If you *really* want to dig deep and inspect email traffic encryption, try [checktls.com](https://checktls.com)'s tool. Here are the results for the domain you provided in your question, which confirms TLS for SMTP traffic on port 465 is in fact encrypted:

```
seconds         test stage and result
[000.001]       Connected to server
[000.084]   <--     220 www4.checktls.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.7/8.14.7; Thu, 17 Aug 2017 03:39:24 -0400
[000.085]       We are allowed to connect
[000.085]    -->    EHLO checktls.com
[000.085]   <--     250-www4.checktls.com Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
              250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
              250-PIPELINING
              250-8BITMIME
              250-SIZE
              250-DSN
              250-ETRN
              250-AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
              250-STARTTLS
              250-DELIVERBY
              250 HELP
[000.086]       We can use this server
[000.086]       TLS is an option on this server
[000.086]    -->    STARTTLS
[000.086]   <--     220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
[000.087]       STARTTLS command works on this server
[000.107]       SSLVersion in use: TLSv1.2
[000.107]       Cipher in use: AES256-SHA256
[000.107]       Connection converted to SSL
[000.110]       

              Certificate 1 of 4 in chain:
              serialNumber= c9:fa:14:5e:b4:99:e5:d4
              subject= /OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=*.checktls.com
              issuer= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
[000.112]       

              Certificate 2 of 4 in chain:
              serialNumber= 7
              subject= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
              issuer= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2

[000.113]       

              Certificate 3 of 4 in chain:
              serialNumber= 1b:e7:15
              subject= /C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
              issuer= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority

[000.114]       

              Certificate 4 of 4 in chain:
              serialNumber= 0
              subject= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
              issuer= /C=US/O=The Go Daddy Group, Inc./OU=Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority

[000.114]       Cert VALIDATED:
[000.114]       Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (127.0.0.1 != *.checktls.com | DNS:*.checktls.com | DNS:checktls.com)
[000.114]       (see RFC-2818 section 3.1 paragraph 4 for info on wildcard ("*") matching)
[000.114]       So email is encrypted but the host is not verified
[000.115]    ~~>    EHLO checktls.com
[000.117]   <~~     250-www4.checktls.com Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
              250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
              250-PIPELINING
              250-8BITMIME
              250-SIZE
              250-DSN
              250-ETRN
              250-AUTH GSSAPI DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
              250-DELIVERBY
              250 HELP
[000.117]       TLS successfully started on this server
[000.118]    ~~>    MAIL FROM:<test@checktls.com>
[000.125]   <~~     250 2.1.0 <test@checktls.com>... Sender ok
[000.125]       Sender is OK
[000.125]    ~~>    RCPT TO:<postmaster@smtp.tiscali.it>
[000.473]   <~~     250 2.1.5 <postmaster@smtp.tiscali.it>... Recipient ok
[000.473]       Recipient OK, email address proofed
[000.473]    ~~>    QUIT
[000.474]   <~~     221 2.0.0 www4.checktls.com closing connection
```